# viso2_ros shows "Visual Odometer got lost!"

Tags: ros, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone.

I'm trying to have a visual odometry with viso2_ros.
**I got some warning and viso2_ros doesn't work well.**
Could you give me some advice ?

I've already finished followings.

1. With usb_cam, camera_calibration and stereo_image_proc, got stereo rectified images
2. With image_view, confirmed that disparity image is published
3. With viso2_ros(stereo_odometer) and rviz, confirmed that viso2_ros publish pose and odometry and it is shown in rviz
4. With rqt_graph, checked that usb_cam, stereo_image_proc and stereo_odometer(viso2) are connected correctly

The problem is occur when a robot which has stereo camera is moved manually.
**When the robot is moved, I get warning "Visual Odometer got lost!" 

and the pose shown in rviz changes slightly.**
For example, the pose changes only 5deg or so even if I rotate the robot to 90deg.

How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Configuration:
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
ROS distro: Groovy
Camera: Logicool USB Web cam(C600) X 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62872/viso2_ros-shows-%22visual-odometer-got-lost!%22/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The viso2_ros stereo_odometer prints this error when the call to VisualOdometryStereo::process() fails. This can have several reasons. If your cameras are not perfectly synchronized (e.g. through a trigger cable), you could try to relax the `match_disp_tolerance` threshold.
If you subscribe to the stereo_odometer/point_cloud topic in rviz, you can see the 3D positions of the features that the stereo_odometer uses. There should be a fair amount of points.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-05-16**:
Thank you! I set the parameter bigger(20), but the warning still appear. I'm not sure that all parameters are set correctly. If camera is towards to front of the robot, x axis of camera frame is along to x axis of the robot, right? Camera frame is attached to a left camera, isn't it?

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-05-20**:
If the camera looks forward, the robot's x axis coincides with the camera's z axis and the robot's y axis coincides with the camera's negative x axis. The camera coordinate system is defined as seen in the top image here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_pipeline/CameraInfo

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-05-20**:
Thank you. I modified tf configuration. However, the warning still appear. Even if I set the param to 100, I have the same situation. Do you have any ideas ?

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-05-21**:
Does the warning appear several times? I think it's normal to appear once in the first iteration. You can also inspect the message published on the `~info` topic, especially the number of matches and the number of inliers.

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-05-26**:
Yes, several times. As you say, I checkd info topic. When the warning appears, the numbers are low. So maybe it is because the environment doesn't have enough features. Thank you.

**Comment by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on 2013-06-04**:
I have exactly the same problem here. When the camera is still, a little motion is found, but when I move the camera I always get a Visual Odometer got lost problem. When I move the camera almost 0 matches and inliners are found. I see the disparity map but not the point cloud, I also have 2 webcams

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-06-04**:
Javie: viso2_ros does not use the disparity map but if that looks fine your stereo system is calibrated well. Maybe your cameras have a lot of motion blur? If they use a rolling shutter this could be a problem as well.